# generating error on printing the hindi script data in utf-8 format

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, nlp

I've tried nearly everything to fix this error but failed!

**my code:**

```
import codecs
import os 
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Piyush\\Desktop\\VISHNU\\wikiextractor-master\\extracted\\AA')
inputfile=codecs.open('wiki_00',encoding='utf-8')
txt=inputfile.read()
print (txt)
```

**filedata:**

```
<doc id="4" url="https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=4" title="विकिपीडिया:Long articles">
विकिपीडिया:Long articles
</doc>
<doc id="5" url="https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=5" title="विकिपीडिया:All pages by title">
विकिपीडिया:All pages by title
</doc>
<doc id="10" url="https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=10" title="हम होंगे कामयाब">
हम होंगे कामयाब
</doc>
<doc id="14" url="https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki?curid=14" title="दैनिक पूजा">
दैनिक पूजा

दैनिक पूजा विधि हिन्दू धर्म की कई उपासना पद्धतियों में से एक है। ये एक दैनिक कर्म है। विभिन्न देवताओं को प्रसन्न करने के लिये कई मन्त्र बताये गये हैं, जो लगभग सभी पुराणों से हैं।
```

**error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "stackk.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (txt)   File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 63-72: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: Are you running this from a cmd shell?

Comment: I am using command prompt in  windows 8.1

Comment: `chcp 65001` before running the script? However, my `python 3.5` runs it smoothly for _any_ `CHCP` I have tested…